# Can't access certain websites in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, internet, browser

I am using 12.04. It was absolutely fine two days ago. But now all my excitement is turned into frustration. I can't open Facebook, Yahoo, Hotmail and many other websites although many other websites just work fine and even I don't have any problem in downloading.

I looked up various solution provided on this forum but neither workout for me. Please help me or I have to uninstall this OS.

My gmail account opens easily.so idont think its a https issue

Comment: Provide us more information. What errors do you get? Edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox then reset your browser.To reset  your browser go to help>>troubleshooting info>>>now u can see the reset option  at your right hand side. u can visit the official website of Firefox for further info.

Comment: Best answer for a messy question.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the sites you have difficulties accessing sites that use https urls? or redirect to https urls?

if so. Check that your computer time and date settings are correct.
SSL certificates (used for https communication) have an expiration date. If the date on your computer is past that date you can experience this problem.